# Перенос телефона в Шапке сайта

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.Сайта на Wp.
Нужно "растянуть" меню на всю ширину экрана и опустить вниз.Сверху в левом углу название магазина( "Магазин часов" ) Слева номер телефона,как в css,это написать,заранее благодарю.
Сам код шапки из файла header.php

```
   <hgroup>

         <?php
            $logo = esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' );
            if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' ) { $logo = $woo_options['woo_logo']; }
            if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' && is_ssl() ) { $logo = preg_replace("/^http:/", "https:", $woo_options['woo_logo']); }
        ?>
        <?php if ( ! isset( $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] ) || $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] != 'true' ) { ?>
            <a id="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" />
            </a>
        <?php } ?>

        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

        <h4 >+7(968)394-13-74<br>круглосуточно</h4>

        <h3 class="nav-toggle"><a href="#navigation">&#9776; <span><?php _e('Navigation', 'woothemes'); ?></span></a></h3>

    </hgroup>

    <?php woo_nav_before(); ?>

    <nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">

        <?php
        if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
            wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fr', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
        } else {
        ?>
        <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
            <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item current_page_item'; ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'woothemes' ); ?></a></li>
            <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>
        </ul><!-- /#nav -->
        <?php } ?>

    </nav><!-- /#navigation -->

    <?php woo_nav_after(); ?>

</header><!-- /#header -->
```

Заранее благодарю за ответы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предыдущих вопросах вы указывали ссылку на [сайт](http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/), советую её и в будущем указывать, так будет проще отвечать на ваши вопросы

1. Для начала зайдите в свой файл стилей CSS (/mystile/css/layout.css) и уберите там ненужные свойства:

строка 601:

```
    #header hgroup {
     /* float: left; */
    }
```

строка 604:

```
    #header #navigation {
     /* float: right;
     clear: none; */
     border: 0;
     background: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
     width: auto;
    }
```

Строка 193:

```
    #header #navigation ul.nav {
     /* float: right; */
    }
```

2. Дальше делайте разметку левого и правого блоков:

   ```
   <hgroup>
    <div class="inner-left">
     <?php
      $logo = esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' );
       if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' ) { $logo = $woo_options['woo_logo']; }
       if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' && is_ssl() ) { $logo = preg_replace("/^http:/", "https:", $woo_options['woo_logo']); }
     ?>
     <?php if ( ! isset( $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] ) || $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] != 'true' ) { ?>
      <a id="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" />
      </a>
     <?php } ?>

     <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

     <h3 class="nav-toggle"><a href="#navigation">&#9776; <span><?php _e('Navigation', 'woothemes'); ?></span></a></h3>

    </div>
    <div class="inner-right">          

     <h4 >+7(968)394-13-74<br>круглосуточно</h4>

    </div>
   </hgroup>
   ```
3. Ну а это соответственно Ваше меню:

   ```
   <?php woo_nav_before(); ?>

   <nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">

    <?php

     if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fr', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );

     } else {

    ?>

    <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">

     <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item current_page_item'; ?>

      <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'woothemes' ); ?></a></li>

     <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>

    </ul><!-- /#nav -->

    ?php } ?>

   </nav><!-- /#navigation -->

   <?php woo_nav_after(); ?>
   ```
4. Управляйте своими блоками через CSS

Comment: Я очень и очень Вам признателен за помощь,еще сам только начинаю разбираться в ВП,но для меня это пока что сложно)
Не могли бы подсказать,я исправил в теге <hgroup>,что вы дали(2 пункт),так же скопировал все в теге <nav> (3 пункт).Но сайт просто падает,и перестает работать,в чем может быть причина?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Все,не стал изменять <nav> .В ксс указал контакты float:left.Все благодарю за развернутый ответ :)

Comment: Извиняюсь за наглость,но все же.Хочу футер перенести на свою страницу html.Скопировал все из файла footer.php и добавил в свой файл( http://tiarsekj.bget.ru ) Но он встал криво,в чем может быть проблема?Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: По порядку, 1. сайт перестал падать? Не думаю что это как-то связано с шапкой, если вы ничего лишнего не удалили

Comment: Контакты float:left!? Вы вроде на макете рисовали, что хотите их вправо перенести!?

Comment: С футером не совсем понятно, нужны примеры, но код футера однозначно должен быть в footer.php

Comment: Почему вы задаете float:right для тега h4, а на для блока inner-right? И для inner-left {float:left}

Comment: Ой,прошу прощения,что-то совершенно запутался,да right,я для заголовка применил это свойство,исправил для дива,не совсем понимаю почему так,наверное,для семантики.Благодарю за поправку.
Насчет футера,по ссылке http://tiarsekj.bget.ru,вы увидите внизу,как расположился футер,хотя весь код я скопировал из footer.php.Не могу понять в чем проблема...

Comment: Нужно смотреть исходный код

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать в разметке стили: `<div class="inner-right" style="float:right;">`. Вы указали `float` в разметке, для этого у вас существует `\mystile\css\layout.css`. Также вы не добавили `float` для блока `inner-left`. Стили: `.inner-left{flat:left;} .inner-right{flat:right;}` Таким образом эти блоки у вас станут на одной высоте